# Weird object in cylinder head preventing spark plug install

Tags: misfire, acura, spark, tl, plug

My friend has an 04 Acura TL (Engine Model J32A3). The car was loosing power and shuddering and the engine light came on. It appears that each cylinder is misfiring. Below is a screenshot of the code faults:

[image: codes]

We decided to check the spark plugs and when we took out spark plug on cylinder 4 and tried to reinstall the plug, we noticed the spark plug did not go in all the way nor did the coil pack. The spark plug tip appeared to be crushed. Inside the cylinder head, there is a metallic ring had pushed up from inside the hole (we assume) that was preventing the spark plug from seating properly. This does not look like it belongs there and have no idea what it is. See images:

[image: not normal]

Here is a picture of cylinder 5 next to it, that appears normal:

[image: normal]

Any ideas on what do at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the spark plug you extracted from cylinder 4 look undamaged (other than the ground being pushed in on it)? See if you can attach a picture of the spark plug from #4 (and maybe even #5).

Answer (score 4):

It appears the threaded portion of the body has broken away from the body itself. The split would have occurred at the point where the image below points to as "spark plug gasket". This could have been done by over tightening the spark plug. The insulator has pulled out from the body and the threads are stuck in the head. You'll need to remove the threads from the head in order to insert a new spark plug. This may require a long "easy out" or bolt extractor. With the easy out, it should be relatively painless to remove. If you cannot find one long enough, you'll have to take it to a shop to have it done. I doubt any damage has occurred to the head, but there is always the chance it has.

[image]